# how to copy more than one jquery-multiselect element when button click?

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen, bootstrap-multiselect

I have a button that are copying up/cloning a select-dropdown and using Choosen Jquery plugin and multiselect plugin. The first element shows perfect but the when i click the button and copy the elements i cant choose from the select list. so only the first instance of the form field works, and not the others added after.

If i have diffrent IDs it will work, but same ID couses issiue. any help how to go around this is appricciated.

```
<script>                        
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#example").multiselect();
     });

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var max_fields = 20; //maximum input boxes allowed

        $(".add_field_button").click(function(e){ //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();

            var add_button = $(this);
            var fieldset   = add_button.closest('fieldset');
            var wrapper    = add_button.closest('.sf-viewport');
            var form       = add_button.closest('form');
            var x          = parseInt(fieldset.attr('data-count'));
            //var cur_height = 0;
            var fieldset_clone;
            var fieldset_content;

            var viewport_height = 0;
            var fieldset_cont   = add_button.closest('.sf-step');


            if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed

                //text box increment
                fieldset.attr('data-count',x+1);

                console.log($(this).siblings().length);

                var cur_height = (fieldset_cont.height() * 1 - 99) / ($(this).siblings().length-1);

                viewport_height = wrapper.height()*1 + cur_height;
                fieldset_cont.height( fieldset_cont.height()*1 +  cur_height );
                wrapper.height(viewport_height);


                fieldset_clone = add_button
                                .closest('fieldset')
                                .find('.fieldset-content')
                                .eq(0)
                                .clone();

                fieldset_clone
                    .find('[name]')
                    .each(function(){
                        $(this).val($(this).prop('defaultValue'));
                    });


                fieldset_content = $('<div>')
                    .addClass('lol')
                    .append(fieldset_clone.children());


                add_button.before(fieldset_content);

                // add remove button
                add_remove_btn(fieldset_content);

            }
        });


        function add_remove_btn(item){
            item.prepend(
                '<a class="btn pull-right om-remove btn-danger" href="#">'+
                '  <div class="small" style="position:relative; z-index:999;">Slett tidsforbruk</div>'+
                '</a>'
            );
        }


        //user click on remove text
        $(document).on("click",".om-remove", function(e){

            e.preventDefault();

            var x = parseInt($(this)
                .closest('lol')
                .attr('data-count')
            );

            $(this)
                .closest('lol')
                .attr('data-count',x-1);

            $(this)
                .closest('.lol')            
                .slideUp(function(){
                    $(this).remove()
            })

            var height = $(this).closest('lol').height();
            var add_button = $(this);
            var viewport_height = 0;
            var fieldset_cont   = add_button.closest('.sf-step');
            var wrapper    = add_button.closest('.sf-viewport');
            var cur_height = (fieldset_cont.height() * 1 - 99) / ($(this).parent().siblings().length-1);

            viewport_height = wrapper.height()*1 - cur_height;
            fieldset_cont.height( fieldset_cont.height()*1 -  cur_height );
            wrapper.height(viewport_height);

        });
    });

</script>
```

**The html**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <fieldset class="fieldset-language" data-count="1">
        <div class="fieldset-content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <select data-placeholder="Choose" id="ny-matrett" tabindex="2" name="ing[]">
                        <option value="">Test<option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input name="gram[]" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="grams">
                        <div class="input-group-addon"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 lol"></div>
            </div>                                                  
            <br><br>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <button class="add_field_button btn btn-warning" data-fields="0" name="add">add</button>    
        <span style="float:right;">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
        </span>
    </fieldset>     
</div>
```

Comment: can you add js fiddle please ?

Comment: Rather hard to add that in jsfidle but can this be fixed with jwuery delegate?

Comment: Updated question some now

Comment: Can you add more code or information please I am not getting you correctly what you want to do ?

Comment: added all of the code now.

Answer (score 0):

You stated the hint I guess. Both objects have the same id. Try to change the id of new object/select. You can remove its id then create a new id using .uniqueId()

https://api.jqueryui.com/uniqueId/

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have made a simple demo that are looks like your requirement let me know ? [Here is my Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sojitrar88/zaqbznwm/)
if for different id  your multi select is working then you can do like this first clone your multiselect then change that id attribute and based on new id call multiselect() method.

I have done like this :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
                $('#example-getting-started').multiselect();
            });
            $('.copymultiselect').on("click",function(){
                var t=new Date().getTime();
                var copied=$('.common:first').clone();
                var abc=copied.attr('id','x_'+t);
                $('.multiselect_list').append(abc);
                $('#x_'+t).multiselect();
            });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="multiselect_list">
        <select id="example-getting-started" multiple="multiple" class="common">
            <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
            <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
            <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
            <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
            <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
            <option value="onions">Onions</option>
        </select>
        <button class="copymultiselect">copy</button>
    </div>
```

Is it correct please ?